# Is it possible to add a method to an EXISTING class at runtime? why or why not?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection.emit

I would imagine this might use Reflection.Emit,

but [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551452/how-to-create-a-method-at-runtime-using-reflection-emit) only answers how to create a class/method dynamically, not how to update an existing class.

In a similar vein, is it possible to delete methods / classes at runtime?  If so, I suppose one could just delete the class, and add it back with its old methods plus the new one.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  I don't have an intended use for this, it is merely a matter of curiosity.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why SO questions should contain only one question per post. Marc and Henk each answered a separate question you asked, and both are good, correct answers. Which one do you choose as  the **right** one and accept? Please restrict yourself to a **single** question per post to avoid this situation, where one of the responders gets rewarded and the other doesn't, even though both answers are good, correct, and answer your question.

Comment: Ok.  I'll try to remember that in the future.  the single-purpose principle for questions instead of methods/objects.  Now that the deed has been done though, I probably shouldn't change it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In regular C# / .NET, the answer is a simple "no". The most you can do is write a `DynamicMethod` which can **behave** like a method of that type (access to private fields etc), but it won't ever be on the API - you just end up with a delegate.

If you use `dynamic`, you can do pretty much anything you want. You can emulate that with `ExpandoObject` by attaching *delegates* in place of methods, but on a custom dynamic type you can do most anything - but this only impacts callers who use the `dynamic` API. For a basic `ExpandoObject` example:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
Func<int, int> func = x => 2*x;
obj.Foo = func;
int i = obj.Foo(123); // now you see it
obj.Foo = null; // now you don't
```

For *properties and events* (not methods), you can use the `System.ComponentModel` approach to  change what appears at runtime, but that only impacts callers who get access via `System.ComponentModel`, which means mainly: UI data-binding. This is how `DataTable` represents columns as pseudo-properties (forgetting about "typed datasets" for the moment - it works without those).

For completeness, I should also mention *extension methods*. Those are more a compiler trick, not a runtime trick - but *kinda* allow you to add methods to an existing type - for small values of "add".

One final trick, commonly used by ORMs etc - is to dynamically **subclass** the type, and provide additional functionality in the subclass. For example, overriding properties to intercept them (lazy-loading, etc).

Comment: haha, "for small values of add".  I guess that means for static methods then :-P.

Comment: @user420667 no, actually I mean "they're not really methods on the type".

Comment: great response.  Any ideas about the why though?  Would it break some sort of development principal / be hard to implement?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to delete methods / classes at runtime?

Suppose that it was possible. Calls to those methods would fail and produce undefined (but usually catastrophic) behaviour.

So I'm sure it is not possible.

Comment: Undefined usually *means* catastrophic! ;)

Comment: catch(UndefinedMethod/UndefinedClassException) ? :-P

Comment: @user420667 There is `MissingMethodException` and `TypeLoadException`. They can happen when you build your code against one version of an assembly, but then run it against another version, which is missing the method or type.

Comment: Just because it could cause runtime errors doesn't mean that's a reason to no being able to do it.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer - in .NET that is a good reason to prevent it.

Comment: Using dynamic you enter the realm of the DLR, so the MissingMethodException will be thrown in runtime, not compile time.