# Is it possible to emit a method in an exsiting type at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add a method to an EXISTING class at runtime? why or why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162094/is-it-possible-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-at-runtime-why-or-why-not)

My question is rather trivial but the answer might not be ;)

**Is it possible to emit a new method in an existing type at runtime ?**

My intuition told me "check Reflection.Emit namespace".

I am however not familiar -yet- with dynamic creation of IL instructions at runtime through Reflection.Emit. I quickly took a first look (and a quick look to such a huge topic is not much) and it seems to me that it is possible to emit brand new types or global methods or other neaty stuff on the fly, but not really possible to add an instance or static method to an existing type (class in my context).

Is it just that I didn't took a close enough look yet to Relfection.Emit or is it just not doable ?

Thanks !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162094/is-it-possible-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-at-runtime-why-or-why-not?lq=1 for the answer to your question - believe this has already been covered on SO hence my vote to close.

Comment: Damn, thanks dash ! How could I not have seen this already existing EXACT similar question. It's getting late I guess ;) Will delete my post