# How to create method in runtime and add it to existing class

Tags: c#, runtime, roslyn, codedom

I have a class like :

```
 public class OverTimeViewModel
    {
        public Guid uniqeid { get; set; }
        public string WorkType { get; set; }
        public int RequestDate { get; set; }
        public string RequestTime { get; set; }

    }
```

I want add Method like:

```
  public string Write(string message)
                    {

                            return message;
                    }
```

is there any way to this by roslyn or codedom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a method to an EXISTING class at runtime? why or why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162094/is-it-possible-to-add-a-method-to-an-existing-class-at-runtime-why-or-why-not)

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Maybe there is another way of doing it...