# How to create an object without calling constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, microsoft-metro

I want to implement some non-standard serialization format.

When I do deserialization I need to create the instance of an object without calling constructors.

There is 

`System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type type)` in `.NET` Framework but there is no `FormatterServices` class in Windows Metro Framework.

Does any body know how to instantiate object without calling to constructor in Windows Metro Framework?

Comment: **You can't.**  Its not clear the reason you think you need to uninitialize your object

Comment: @Ramhound, the reason is that I don't know which constructor to invoke if there is no default constructor. I suppose that `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` works in the same way, because when it deserialize object, it doesn't call any constructors.

Comment: Iirc, on .netcore DataContractSerializer (and friends) *do* run a parameterless constructor. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @ramhound that isn't to "uninitialize" an object - it is to create an object without initializing it - pretty common in serialization.

Comment: @alexander out of curiosity, what is the format? Is it something that would be of general use? Or is it specific to your scenario? The reason I ask: I am deeply involved in serialization code, and I have existing techniques / tools for targeting .netcore and other platforms. If it would be useful to other devs, I might be able to find some time to help you put together a F/OSS library for the purpose (gratuitously stealing large chunks of the protobuf-net source). If not, well, you still might find some of that code useful for reference.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thank for you answer. I work on the library, the purpose of which, is to provide simplified api for [MIME-DIR](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2425) based types implementation, such as [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) or [VCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar).  The idea is that user writes:  `[MimeRecordEntry(Name = "PHOTO")]  public Photo Photo { get; set; }`  and serializer transform it to:  `PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:1h...N0`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know: you can't. You also can't call a private/protected/internal constructor: .netcore has restricted reflection (like the Silverlight  model, but with the added pain of GetTypeInfo()).

The only option I can suggest is maybe provide separate support for a user-supplied factory method that does the appropriate things, or similarly the ability to pass in a factory interface. This takes construction away from the serialization engine, and puts it back in control of code that knows about the specific types.

Answer (score 0):

i may be wrong but when you instanciate an object you must, at least, run a constructor. Even if no constructor is declared, a default empty constructor is called. Instanciation makes a class become an object.

So to me your question has no answer.

Maybe you could build a default empty constructor at runtime if needed. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551452/how-to-create-a-method-at-runtime-using-reflection-emit)

Comment: The OP is correct: in regular .net you can indeed create an instance without executing any constructors. This is atypical, and is usually only used by library code like serialization engines, RPC/proxy tools, and database ORM tools. The real question is: "this feature that exists in regular .net: does it exist in .netcore?". Also, you can't add constructors to existing types via reflection, and reflection-emit doesn't exist **at all** in .netcore.