# Is it possible writing code that generate a class, method, member at runtime ?

Tags: c#, .net

**Is it possible writing code that generate a class, method, member at runtime using .NET (C#)?**

For more details consider this scenario :

create a **dynamic workflow program** to enable user for creating his own process, activities, and writing dynamic SQL SPs, …, and collect all this stuff together then *generate* a **classes**, member **variables** , member **functions** , **UIs**, **conditions**, … dynamically at run-time ! in other word your own ***dynamic code factory framework*** !

Comment: Take a look at the [TypeBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx)

Comment: There is an interesting project on CodeProject, Compiling C# code during runtime: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10324/Compiling-code-during-runtime - Maybe this will help

Comment: Please be aware that this easily can become very messy, and if you let your users introduce runtime code you're opening a potential security risk.. Especially when your application requires admin rights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are various options for this:

- Use [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) (the [`System.CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) namespace)
- Use the [`System.Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace
- Create C# code and then compile it with [`Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)
- For individual methods, create an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) and then compile it to a delegate
- Use the [Roslyn CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx) to either compile C# code or create your own AST and compile that

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer: Yes!**

For a detail of how to achieve this you would want to start your learning by looking at [`Reflection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx).

The next step would be looking for other resources on the internet and a quick search located this question on SO:

[How to create a method at runtime using Reflection.emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551452/how-to-create-a-method-at-runtime-using-reflection-emit)

[Dynamic Language Runtime](http://dlr.codeplex.com/) may also be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

The short response is yes. You have to look and study the following technologies:

[CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)

[Windows Wordflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx)

If it is anyway useful can be discussed: One able to "dynamically" program a workflow in a so specific mode will probably prefer to write the code by hand himself.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative of using *strong types* in this case, you may consider also using
[Dynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx) object to allow *fully featured* dynamic behaviour.

Could be more appropriate then strong typing generated at runtime, in *this* case.